# Flutter how to hide a scrollbar(thumb) in scrollable widgets like Listview.builder, SingleChildScrollView, etc

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, scrollbar

Is there any way to remove scrollbar from a `SingleChildScrollView` and `Listview.builder`? After the latest update, it **appears automatically while scrolling** (Platform Windows).

**I've tried this solution:**

```
 NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
     onNotification: (_) => true,
     child: ...,
    );
```

**And also tried to wrap my widget tree in a Scrollbar widget** with isAlwaysShown and controller, but both variants didn't work.

[image: Still here]

Answer (score 75, accepted):

To hide a scrollbar on desktop/web wrap your widget tree in a ScrollConfiguration widget with behavior of ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: false),

```
 ScrollConfiguration(
      behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: false),
      child: ...,),
```

or you can add scrollBehavior to MaterialApp widget

```
class NoThumbScrollBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
        PointerDeviceKind.stylus,
        PointerDeviceKind.trackpad,
      };
}

return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      scrollBehavior: NoThumbScrollBehavior().copyWith(scrollbars: false),
      home: MainWindow(),
    );
```

Comment: Add also PointerDeviceKind.trackpad into the dragDevices getter for the ones who use laptops without a mouse '^^

Comment: Thank you, i've updated the example, however, i tested the overall behavior of my app without this trackpad support and it's working great on the laptop, so i don't really see the reason of adding such behavior support to the app

Comment: Thanks :) I commented that because it wasn't working for me. Only adding that line that worked. I'm using an Intel MacBook Air.

Answer (score 19):

Wrap your scrollable widget in [ScrollConfiguration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollConfiguration-class.html)

```
ScrollConfiguration(
 behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: false),
 child: ListView(...)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and quickest way to achieve this is to set `thickness: 0` on the Scrollbar widget. It'll look something like this:

```
 Scrollbar(
          thickness: 0,
          child: ...
 )
```

Comment: It didn't worked for me in showGeneralDialog()