# Remove the scroll bar itself from the flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows

If you scroll through physics: const Never Scrollable ScrollPhysics() in SingleChildScrollView from the plutter, you will not be able to scroll, but if you bring the mouse to the right of the Container, a scroll bar will appear.

It's not a problem when using ios and android, but when using windows app, moving the mouse will cause a scrollbar to appear and it's uncomfortable.

I know it has the ability to block scrolling in the flutter, but how do I keep the scrollbar from appearing?
I searched Google hard, but I couldn't find it.

I'd be so grateful if someone could help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter how to hide a scrollbar(thumb) in scrollable widgets like Listview.builder, SingleChildScrollView, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67662141/flutter-how-to-hide-a-scrollbarthumb-in-scrollable-widgets-like-listview-build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try `ScrollbarTheme` interactivity

### Set it to false

Setting it at the theme:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    scrollbarTheme: ScrollbarThemeData(interactive: false),
  ),
);
```

Setting it above the widget

```dart
ScrollbarTheme(
     data: ScrollbarThemeData(interactive: false),
     child: SingleChildScrollView(),
);
```